# Blender as a Python Module: Import COLLADA

Tags: scripting, import, collada

I followed [this post](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) to install blender as a python module. I realize that this isn't officially supported, but I thought I'd ask for help anyways.

I'm trying to import a COLLADA (.dae) file. In blender's scripting mode, this is done by the method `bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=...)`. However, when I checked to see if this method exists, I got

```
>>> bpy.ops.wm.collada_import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/2.74/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 207, in __repr__
    as_string = op_as_string(idname)
AttributeError: _bpy.ops.as_string: operator "WM_OT_collada_import" could not be found
```

Other import methods, such as `bpy.ops.import_scene.autodesk_3ds` work, so I'm wondering if there's an easy way to fix this.

Comment: Any solution after all?